# How Does Adding Regressors Affect Standard Errors and Existing Coefficients?

Tags: regression

(First off, bonus points if you can write my question title more clearly)

My project right now is to research citizenship status and income.

At first my regression was like this:

$$ INCOME = \beta0 + \beta1STATUS $$

Now, I am going to do one with control variables like this:
$$ INCOME = \beta0 + \beta1STATUS + \beta2EDUCATION + \beta3ZIPCODE$$
When I'm looking at the coefficient and standard error for immigration status, what does the regression of earnings on immigration status and all my control variables tell me compared to a regression of just earnings on immigration status? Generally in regressions, how does adding more variables change standard errors and coefficients?

Comment: As far as your question about coefficients, this question has been answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/does-adding-more-variables-into-a-multivariable-regression-change-coefficients-o

Comment: And for your question about standard errors, it is answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97179/how-are-standard-errors-affected-in-a-multivariate-regression

Comment: The correct answer is that it depends. What's most likely going to happen in your case though is that the standard errors will go up and the coefficient will go down.

Comment: Whoever fixed my title question, here's some bonus points. +1,000,000!

Comment: @DornerA, those helped so much! Thank you!

Comment: You are quite welcome! If I have econometrics questions I always comb through the stats stackexchange before asking because they have a very large and established community so odds are your question has been asked before. It's a great resource for us economists!